# Qt: Background color on QStandardItem using StyleSheet

Tags: qt

I have a class that inherits QStandardItem and I put the elements in a QTreeWidget. The class receives notifications from the outside and I want to change the background color of the item based on what happened.

If I do not use stylesheets, it works just fine, like this:

```
void myClass::onExternalEvent()
{
    setBackground(0, QColor(255,0,0))); 
}
```

However, as soon as I put a stylesheet on the QTreeWidget, this has no effect : the stylesheet seems to override the `setBackground()` call.

So I tried :

```
void myClass::onExternalEvent()
{
    this->setStyleSheet("background-color: red"); 
}
```

but this is probably all wrong, it changed the color of some other element on my screen, not sure why.

Does anyone have an idea on how I can alter the background color like with setBackgroundColor but still be able to use stylesheet on my QTreeWidget?

Answer (score 0):

Palettes propagate to the children of a widget, and it's bad to mix and match style-sheet controls and native controls (I do not have a citation for the latter handy, but I have read it in the QT docs *somewhere*).

That being said, try setting `setAutoFillBackground(false)` on your `QStandardItem` derived class.

**EDIT:** Sorry - also, are you specifying the `QTreeWidget` in the stylesheet or just setting "background-color:"? If you specify the `QTreeWidget` only in the stylesheet that might take care of it as well.

```
QTreeWidget { background-color: white; }
```

But I think you still have to set the `autoFillBackground(false)`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I did not get any different result with setAutoFillBackground. The doc says it will be turned off anyway if there is a stylesheet:
http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qwidget.html#autoFillBackground-prop

The thing is that I do not want to change the background for the full QTreeWidget, only for a specific item (a row) inside the widget. My class is a QTreeWidgetItem and I would like to change the color of this item only.